# Twig - How to render an HTML rating element

Tags: php, twig

What I am trying to achieve is to render a simple 5-star rating HTML element based on a number ( 0-5 )

Example :

```
 {{ user.rating }} // returns integer 4
```

Output should be:

```
<div class="rating">
     <i class="star voted"></i>
     <i class="star voted"></i>
     <i class="star voted"></i>
     <i class="star voted"></i>
     <i class="star-empty"></i>
</div>
// 4 lighted stars out of 5
```

Thanks

Comment: What css and JavaScript have you tried?

Comment: @khled What's the JS for ? This is related to Twig, I don't need JS as for the CSS the class 'voted' is obvious it gives a certain color..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can archive your problem with this code:

```
<div class="rating">
{% for i in 1..5 %}
{% set starClass = (user.rating >= i ? "star voted" : "star-empty")  %}
     <i class="{{ starClass }}"></i>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

[See the working solution on this twigfiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/bz35ar)

**Explanation:**

From the [doc](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html):

> If you do need to iterate over a sequence of numbers, you can use the
>   .. operator:
>
> ```
> {% for i in 0..10 %}
>     * {{ i }}
> {% endfor %}
> ```

The Twig built-in `..` operator is just syntactic sugar for the [range function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/range.html).

Comment: Thanks Matteo! Yes, exactly was I was trying to do, can you please explain what is the "1..5" ? why is there two dots and what does it stand for ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple way :

```php
{% set stars, count,starsResult = 4 , 1 , "" %}

{% for i in range(1, 5) %}


     
{% if stars >= count %}

{% set starsResult = starsResult ~ "<i "star active">" %}

{% else %}
{% set starsResult = starsResult ~ "<i class="star disable">" %}

{% endif %}

{% set count = count + 1 %}

{% endfor %}

{{ starsResult }}
```